# Rails 3 CMS that doesn't mess with your application's code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system

For a client I have to build a CMS with my Rails 3.2.2 application. The thing is, the app is ready-to-go. Without the CMS, that is. I just have to implement a CMS, but when I tried to do that with RefineryCMS (following Refinery's own instructions), it didn't work, because Refinery didn't pick up the CSS and pages I had made.

What should I do? Is there another, useful CMS-plugin for an existing Rails app? Or should I build a CMS myself, with stuff such as omni-auth? If so, is there a tutorial around for building such a CMS?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [copycopter](http://railscasts.com/episodes/336-copycopter) it might fit your needs.

Comment: Copycopter only allows you to change text through a separate Rails app. I don't see how that could be considered a CMS.

Comment: @TerencePonce You're correct it's not a full fledged CMS. Thus the "it might fit your needs". If all he wants it copy management, which is the reason a lot of people use CMS tools, then it does a really good job and is not invasive.

Comment: Yeah I just want my client to be able to change the content of the website on his own. Can he do that with copycopter?

Comment: Again it depends which content. If he needs to be able to add pictures and change formatting and stuff that a CMS generally provides, then copycopter is not good for you.  If they only need to change the 'copy', which is the text, then it might be perfect. Watch the railscast and you'll have a better understanding.

Comment: Can't I build my own? With omni-auth, kaminari, etc? Is there a tutorial around for that?